# How do I write a compound query in firebase that includes a timestamp

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a compound query in my cloud function that counts all documents with timestamp greater than current time. I have two questions:
1. Will my current structure of storing time stamp as string in firestore be okay or should I be saving it as firestore time stamp?
2. In either case, how do I write the compound query?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var db = admin.firestore();

exports.welcomeData = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
        'while authenticated.');
  }

  const uid = context.auth.uid;
  var currentDateTime = new Date()
  var numberRequestsPosted = 0

  var requestsRef = db.collection('requests');
  var query = await requestsRef.where('createdBy', '==', uid)
 .where('fromDateAndTime','>',currentDateTime).get()
.then(snapshotRequests => {
  if (snapshotRequests.empty) {
    console.log('WelcomeData: No matching documents.');
  }
  else {
    snapshotRequests.forEach(request => {
      numberRequestsPosted++;
    })
  }
})

return {
    numberRequestsPosted: numberRequestsPosted.toString(),
    };
});
```

My document has a document field of type string called fromDateAndTime that is stored in the following format: 4/24/2019 2:00 AM

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to store timestamps as strings.  It's better to use the provided timestamp field type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that the easiest and most universal way to store timestamps is in the GMT integer version for a couple of reasons: `for example: 1556198939`

1. Every single programming language and computer has this function built in.
2. Calculations are simple and efficient `> int < int`
3. Every programming language has a way to convert this to their local date format and every language can change this to a local timezone.

So save yourself some time and headache and store your date-times as a GMT integer.

Also, remember to do this `var timeStamp = Date.now()/1000` because node works on millisecond timescales.